# How to strikeout text of QStandardItem in Qt/PyQt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, text-styling, qstandarditem

I have a `QStandardItemModel` in PySide, and want to strikeout text on certain rows (it is a to do list application and when a task is done, I want to strike through the text). Given a `QStandardItem` that displays fine, [based on the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#setFont) I try to strikethrough the text with:

```
QStandardItem.setFont(QtGui.QFont.setStrikeOut(True))
```

But the text is unchanged, and I get error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'setStrikeOut' requires a 'PySide.QtGui.QFont' object but received a 'bool'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setStrikeOut` returns `void` and you should not pass it as the argument for `setFont`. You should pass an instance of `QFont` there.

It would be better to retrieve the font of the item in question, set its  strikeout property, and then set this revised `QFont` as the new font of the item :

```
f = item.font()
f.setStrikeOut(True)
item.setFont(f)
```

This way you would keep other options of the item's font previously set.